# I have problem with discord.py TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a problem with creating a command to load information about the Bitcoin price.

Error in console:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str`

Here is the code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def bitcoin(ctx):
    url = 'http://api.coinlayer.com/live?access_key='
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        raw_response = await session.get(url)
        response = await raw_response.text()
        response = json.loads(response)
        await ctx.send("Bitcoin price is: $" + response['rates']['BTC'])
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your `response['rates']['BTC']` is a float and therefore you can not directly concat it to a string using the `+`

User `str()` to convert it to str or use f-strings `f"Bitcoin price is: $ {response['rates']['BTC']}"`